# What's the best alternative to using the $\sin^2x$ notation?

Tags: trigonometry, notation

Although I understand that $\sin^2x$ refers to $(\sin x)^2$, and *not* $\sin(\sin(x))$, I find this notation to be confusing—often it can hamper my thinking. For instance, if I was solving the following equation:

$$
\sin^2x-\frac{7}{2}\sin x-2=0
$$

I might not realise that there is a squared term and a linear term, and hence it is a quadratic in $\sin x$. If on the other hand I wrote:

$$
(\sin x)^2-\frac{7}{2}\sin x-2=0
$$

then it would be much clearer to me what is going on. So what is the best alternative to writing $\sin^2x$? The obvious answer is to write $(\sin x)^2$, but at times this can feel cluttered, particularly if there are other bracketed terms. So is there a better solution that avoids this notational issue?

Comment: I have never seen any other notation besides $(\sin x)^2$.

Comment: That said, another way to handle an equation like the one you describe is to introduce another variable: "consider the equation $y^2-\frac{7}{2}y-2=0$ where $y=\sin x$."  This avoids the $\sin^2 x$ notation as well as the "clutter".

Comment: You can just assume it as some variable

Comment: I rarely use the juxtaposed $\sin x$ instead of the functional $\sin(x)$. With the functional notation it is obvious whether we square the sinus $\sin(x)^2$ or the variable $\sin(x^2)$.

Comment: The notation $(\sin x)^2$ is not any more cluttered than $\sin^2x$ is. But in the first place, rather than writing $\sin x$, it would be far more adequate if you wrote $\sin(x)$ instead. Sure, this requires writing brackets, but the payoff is that every single problem with the notation goes away. It is completely worth it. Now, an obvious distinction between $\sin^2(x)$, $\sin(x)^2$, and $\sin(x^2)$ exists, whereas with the notation without brackets, such a distinction is completely ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to get goofy with $\sin(x)$, which you could denote $\sin_x$ which isn't confusing since sine isn't taking any arguments besides $x$ in that equation. You could terse-ify this even more to $\mathrm{s}_x$. So you get
$$
\mathrm{s}_x^2-\frac{7}{2}\mathrm{s}_x-2=0
$$
But this is all just a complicated way to do basically what [Nate did here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764427/whats-the-best-alternative-to-using-the-sin2x-notation/3764440#comment7744559_3764427) and say "let $\mathrm{s}_x = \sin(x)$ ..."

Comment: In my considered professional opinion: ewwww.

Comment: @NateEldredge in my unprofessional opinion … I agree

Comment: @MikePierce I like this idea, although I'd prefer to write $s$ instead of $s_x$, even thought the latter notation is more informational. This all depends on the context of course: writing $s$ for $\sin x$ is clearly a bad idea if you have also have $\sin y$ in your equation.